# Simple Search function with jQuery to search items doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm, api, search

I am trying to making a simple app that calls an api and get users data. When users data displayed on the page I want to search users with their usernames. tried many many times but its not working. Can anybody please help?

```js
var base = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/";
var key = "myKey&callback";
var users = ["ESL_SC2", "OgamingSC2", "cretetion", "freecodecamp",
             "storbeck", "habathcx", "RobotCaleb", "noobs2ninjas",
             "TwinGalaxiesLive","MedryBW", "frontender007","Gronkh"];



$(document).ready(function(){
  requestData(users);
  searchUsers($("a"));

});

function requestData ( arr ) {
  arr.forEach ( function ( user ) {
    var url = base + user + '/?client_id=' + key + '&callback=?';
    $.getJSON(url, function ( json ) {
      
      displayChannel(json);
      
    });
  });
}

function displayChannel( obj ) {
  var name, status, logo, url, game;
  
  name = obj.display_name;
  status = obj.status;
  logo = obj.logo;
  url = obj.url;
  game = obj.game;
  
  var channel,onoff;

  if ( status && status.length > 16) {
   status = status.substr(0, 16) + "....";
  }


  if ( game === null ) {
   onoff = "offline";
  }
  else {
   onoff = "online";
  }
  
  channel = "<a>";
  channel +=  "<h3>" + name + "</h3>";
  channel += "<img src='" + logo + "'>";
  channel += "<p>" + status + "</p>";
  $(channel).attr('class', onoff);

  $("#container").append(channel);
  
  
}


function searchUsers( arr ) {
 var searchBox = $("input[type='text']");

 $(searchBox).keyup( function(){

  var chars = $(searchBox).val();

  $("arr").each(function (item){
   if($(item).find('h3').text().indexOf(chars) < 0) {
    $(this).parent().closest('a').hide();
   }
   else {
    $(this).parent().closest('a').show();
   }
  });
 });
}
```

```css
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}
body {
 line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}

/************************************************************/

header {
  width: 960px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 20px auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

header form {
  float: right;
}

header form input {
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
#container {
  width: 960px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #cecece;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

a {
  width: 140px;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 40px;
  float: left;

}

a img {
  width: 140px;
  height: 80px;
}

h3 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  float: left;
}

p {
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="twitch.css">
  <title> Twitch TV</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  <header>
   <form action="#">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="radio"> All
    <input type="radio"> Online
    <input type="radio"> Offline
   </form>
  </header>

  <div id="container">

  
    
  </div>
 

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="twitch.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to update your code i hope this helps

```
    var base = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users/";
var key = "myKey&callback";
var users = ["ESL_SC2", "OgamingSC2", "cretetion", "freecodecamp",
             "storbeck", "habathcx", "RobotCaleb", "noobs2ninjas",
             "TwinGalaxiesLive","MedryBW", "frontender007","Gronkh"];



$(document).ready(function(){
  requestData(users);
  searchUsers(users);

});

function requestData ( arr ) {
  arr.forEach ( function ( user ) {
    var url = base + user + '/?client_id=' + key + '&callback=?';
    $.getJSON(url, function ( json ) {

      displayChannel(json);

    });
  });
}

function displayChannel( obj ) {
  var name, status, logo, url, game;

  name = obj.display_name;
  status = obj.status;
  logo = obj.logo;
  url = obj.url;
  game = obj.game;

  var channel,onoff;

  if ( status && status.length > 16) {
    status = status.substr(0, 16) + "....";
  }


  if ( game === null ) {
    onoff = "offline";
  }
  else {
    onoff = "online";
  }

  channel = "<a id="+name+">";
  channel +=  "<h3>" + name + "</h3>";
  channel += "<img src='" + logo + "'>";
  channel += "<p>" + status + "</p>";
  $(channel).attr('class', onoff);

  $("#container").append(channel);


}


function searchUsers( arr ) {
    var searchBox = $("input[type='text']");

        var chars = $(searchBox).val();

        $.each( arr, function( i, val ) {

            if(val==chars) {
                $('a#'+chars).siblings().hide();
            }
            else {
                $(this).parent().closest('a').show();
            }
        });

}
$("input[type='text']").change(function(){

    searchUsers(users);
});
```